# Iterate over Dictionary with java-script selector

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, javascriptserializer

I have a Dictionary in my view, there are 
[inputID, tooltip].

Also i have a set of id's of my input elements in this page.
I need to iterate through the dictionary with my elements ids:

```
 @{
 Dictionary<string, string> questionMarks = 
     ViewBag.QuestionMarks as Dictionary<string, string>;
 @}

 <script type="java-script">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var inputs = $('input,select[type!="hidden"]');
    $.each(inputs, function(i, val) {
    if ($(val).attr('id')) { 
                var id = $(val).attr('id');

                var iter_string = '@questionMarks' + "[" + id + "]";
                alert(iter_string);              // [1]
                alert('@questionMarks["cvc"]');  // here i got tooltip
             }
    });
</script>
```

[1] i have System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String, System.String][cvc]

Thanks to Jan Jongboom,
**Finally** i got that i wanted:

```
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization
@{
    Dictionary<string, string> questionMarks = ViewBag.QuestionMarks as Dictionary<string, string>;
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
@}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var questionMarks = @Html.Raw(jss.Serialize((Dictionary<string, string>)ViewBag.QuestionMarks));     
    $(document).ready(function () {
        for ( keyVar in questionMarks ) {
            $('#' + keyVar).attr('original-title', questionMarks[keyVar]);
            $('#' + keyVar).tipsy({ gravity: 'w' });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Its possible but not quite the way your doing it. Even done another way its really a fairly horrible way to do it. What are you planning on doing with it? (Im assuming you dont want to just alert it all?)

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. I want to use 'tipsy' plugin to jquery, to get tooltips for my input elements. 
But tooltip text can be edited, so its storing in database, 
and this way i want to transfer tooltip textx from db to view

so i than i will do these:
   $('#cvc').attr('original-title', 'tooltiptext');
   $('#cvc').tipsy({ gravity: 'w'});

Comment: I would recommend attaching data attributes to the elements and then running a script that parses them after the page has loaded. Far better approach. So for each element that is drawn you add data-tooltiptext="Text here" then in your loop (Run on document ready) you do $(element).data('tooltiptext') to get it back and pass it into your tooltip plugin. I can put together an example if you need.

Comment: Or do you mean that the tooltips can change without a page refresh and thus without the inputs being redrawn? If so use JSON to request the data via ajax and update it that way.

Comment: now, tooltip can be changed in separate page in admin area.

Comment: Then you should definitely attatch data attributes to your inputs! Ill get an example together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like

```
<script>
var questionMarks = @new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize((Dictionary<string, string>)ViewBag.QuestionMarks) ;
</script>
```

Now you have a javascript variable called `questionMarks` that you can iterate over.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you had asked. Mainly because moving data like that directly into scripts is an awful idea. Scripts should always be in separate files and not written out directly into a view, makes for difficult maintenance. If I wrote JS in views id get told off, if I did something like that I'm fairly confident id be laughed out of the office. Just goes against too many conventions and separation.

Comment: I don't consider this bad. You can use a lib like [Moth](https://github.com/janjongboom/Moth) to load 'em at the bottom of the page. Complete modules should be in seperate files, but you will have moments where you want (need!) to kick off a script with data from your view. Therefore inline javascript should not considered bad, as long as it's a reasonable amount. It also makes more sense if doing simple small UI bits that only affect the current view to put 'em inside the view. Anyhow, how would you pass data from the model to the script without writing inline js?

Comment: Ill have to take a look at Moth, always good to see different perspectives. The way I would suggest doing it is how I detailed in my answer below, attaching data attributes to inputs when they are drawn is a good way to end up with separation. So the HTML inputs would have data-somename and when you then get your list of inputs via jquery instead of looking through the array in the way suggested you just do $(input).data('somename') and use that. So for example TextBoxFor(x => x.FieldName, new { data_somename = "value" });  the value in this case coming from the view data.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't iterate from the client side code through server variable. You can generate initialization code from JS variable (like JSON) or generate necessary html on the server side. Also you can requests for such data on from jsavascript via ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Attatching data attributes to the inputs as they are drawn should help you with this one.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Krch9/

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var inputs = $("input", "#container");
    $.each(inputs, function(i, val) {
        var ToolTipText = $(this).data('tooltiptext');
        /// Run your tooltip plugin here ...
        $("#output").html($("#output").html() + "<br>" + $(this).attr('id') + " : " + ToolTipText);
    });
});
```

Using MVC helpers you can easily add them:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Field, new { data_tooltiptext = "Blah blah"});
```

The markup would end up looking something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="Field" data-tooltiptext="Blah blah">
```

Edit: Extra help

I.E Loop through your elements

```
foreach( var question in questionMarks) {
   @Html.TextBox(question.Key, new { data_tooltiptext = question.Value} );
}
```

Then use the javascript example (Youll need to modify it to your needs ...) to run the plugin on the elements

Comment: Thank you for helping, it's clear. 
The problem now is get array of objects in js, and not a string (see update)

Comment: I understand what your trying to do but moving data into a js array like that is absolutely horrible. I'm fairly sure I wouldnt have a job left if I wrote code like that. I wont be helping you to do it that way but I'm sure there will be someone else here willing to help.

Comment: Ok, but what you suppose as opposite to move data in js array? I want to get the best solution.

I want to clarify: i need this array, to set attribute of each input element.

Comment: I have explained how, you need to attatch the data attributes to each element and then when you loop through them you get the data attribute off the element and set it for the tool tip. Follow the link in my answer to see a demonstration. So you need to set two data attributes by the look of what your trying to do.

Comment: But i don't have this text into their attributes - its loading from db and transferring through viewdata. That's why i need js array!

Comment: You can take the view data and put it into the inputs ... I dont think you understand what I'm getting at here. Perhaps I can link you to some tutorials for basic usage of MVC? YOU have to put the attributes there, you take the view data and add it to them yourself. I.E Loop through your elements foreach( var question in questionMarks) { @Html.TextBox(question.Key, new { data_tooltiptext = question.Value} ); }

Comment: I have added additional information on the end of my answer ... You don't HAVE to have it in a javascript array ... There are other better ways of doing it more in keeping with standards. Such as storing the data in a data attribute then when you loop through using that.

Comment: Yes, i'm understanding what are you talking about. 
Maybe links will help to understand

Comment: I read your sample more one time, i think, now i understand you.
So you propose is to create textboxes dynamically with setted values that i need already. but i have complex ready html layout, there are many <div>'s behind this textboxes.

Comment: So i decided to do like this: 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyModel.CreatorFirstName, loaded_data = questionMarks["CompanyModel_CreatorFirstName"] })

Comment: Is that writing out the markup as you would expect it? With all the correct stuff? You have to use data_NAMEHERE as it is a HTML5 standard and jquery will not work using .data otherwise. You could do it manually but its always best to use conventions. (Sorry for the slow replies, a little busy)

Comment: Well now I just feel like I've wasted my time hah. Good luck to you ;)

Answer (score -1):

To remove the quotes, use Html.Raw()

```
var questionMarks = '@Html.Raw(jss.Serialize((Dictionary<string, string>)ViewBag.QuestionMarks))';
```